# How to convert a single included child entity (one-to-one) to simple object in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to convert a child of an Entity Framework entity instance into a simple class but am running into some difficulties. Here is my relevant code:

```
model.BlogSearchResults = await _context.Blog
                                .Include(b => b.Survey)
                                .Select(b => new BlogSearchResult
                                {
                                    Id = b.Id,
                                    Title = b.Title,
                                    Summary = b.Summary,
                                    SurveySearchResult = b.Survey == null ? null : new SurveySearchResult
                                    {
                                        Id = b.Survey.Id,
                                        Title = b.Survey.Title,
                                        Description = b.Survey.Description
                                    }
                                }).ToListAsync();
```

This is failing on the line that sets `SurveySearchResult` with an `ArgumentException` error. I believe this is because `Blog.Survey` is technically nullable? If I cast `b.Survey.Id` to a non-nullable int I end up getting an error that states: `AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Models.Blog'.)`.

Since `Survey` has a one-to-one relationship with `Blog` I cannot convert it into a simple object using lambda expressions as you might with a list child. I have tried something like this:

`SurveySearchResult = (b.Survey => new SurveySearchResult{ ...`

with no luck and have tried using a helper function to manually convert the object over in-line. Nothing seems to work. Is there a standard way of doing this I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your posted code. `ArgumentException` is thrown generally when there's something "invalid" about an argument passed to a method or constructor. Usually, you get something like `ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, which derive from `ArgumentException` and give more explicit detail about what's actually wrong with the argument.

However, here, there's nothing that should really cause this particular exception. The only arguments you're passing are to `Include` and `Select`, and those are perfectly fine. It's possible there's something on `BlogSearchResult` or `SurveySearchResult` that's generating this error, but you haven't posted the code for those classes, making it impossible to tell.